# Remove "powered by Magento" from footer

Tags: frontend, ce-1.7.0.2

I would like to remove `powered by Magento` from the footer.

It's not in CMS blocks "footer_links".

**HTML source code**

```
<p class="bugs"> - <a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking" 
onclick="this.target='_blank'"><strong>powered by Magento</strong></a> (Version 1.7.0.2)</p>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Enable Template Path Hints (System -> Configuration; choose your store view; Developer -> Debug)
2. You will find out that the default file is: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml` (don't touch this file)
3. Copy it to:  `app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/page/html/footer.phtml`
4. Clear cache, reload.

Then you can modify this file as you want.

Answer (score 8):

The "brute-force" method would be to do a full-project code-search for a unique string, such as `class="bugs"` to find the right location.

The more educated way is of course to use template hints as Tim pointed out.

Comment: I don't know if template path hints are necessarily the "more educated way" of finding the template. I often find that using `grep` from SSH is faster (depending on what you're looking for).

Comment: I agree with @pspahn, grep can be quicker...and depending on the site you are working on (I've seen this in sites I have inherited) HTML issues can stop the template hints from working

Comment: I personally like this method better since this can be applied to a broader range of issues.